# Node JS: variable usage between modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have two modules to represent my problem/confusion:

f2.js:

```
var user;

var getName = function(userName) {
    user = userName;
    return user;
};

module.exports.getName = getName;
module.exports.user = user;
```

f1.js:

```
var userName = require('./f2.js');
console.log(userName.getName("myName"));

// I need below to return "myName" too - how?
console.log(userName.user);
```

When I run f1.js, I get these:

```
myName
undefined
```

What am I missing in terms of scoping or perhaps asynchronous coding? Logically, I know getName function will always run in front so how can I read 'user' variable in other modules as set with that pre-run function? I eventually want to expand this with express and use it as site login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach the name into an instance of User function like so:

```js
function createUser() {
  this.name = '';
  return { 
    user : this.user,
    getName: function(userName) {
        this.user = userName;
        return this.user;
    },
  }
}

var newUser = createUser();

module.exports.getName = newUser.getName;
module.exports.user = newUser.user;
```

This assumes that you only have one instance of `User` though. Otherwise you might want to export the whole function instead and use it like so:

```js
// exports createUser function instead
module.exports.createUser = createUser;


// in other files
var createUser = require('../path/createUser.js');

var bobby = createUser();
bobby.getName('bobby'); // will return 'bobby'

console.log(bobby.user); // will also return 'bobby'
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for to do this with objects as well

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
userName.getName(username){
console.log(username);
});
```

if async's the problem then

f2.js

```
var user;

var getName = function(userName,callback) {
    user = userName;
    callback(user);
};

module.exports.getName = getName;
module.exports.user = user;
```

f1.js

```
var userName = require('./f2.js');
    userName.getName(username, function(uname) {
    console.log(uname);
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround. It'll get you what you're looking for, but it's not really satisfying.

In f2.js:

```
var getName = function(userName, user) {
    user = userName;
    return user;
};

module.exports.getName = getName;
```

In f1.js:

```
var userName = require('./f2.js');
var user;
console.log(userName.getName("myName", user));

console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `exports.user` and `var user` are independent copies. Initially, they hold the same value, but changes to one don't impact the other, similar to with other variables:

```
var foo = 'one';
var bar = foo; // copies the value
bar = 'two';
console.log(foo, bar); // "one" "two"
```

To have `exports.user` always provide `var user`'s value, one option is to define the former as a [getter property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty), returning the latter:

```
Object.defineProperty(module.exports, 'user', {
    get: function () {
        return user;
    }
});
```

Or, assign it to the function directly, though other modules will need to call it:

```
module.exports.user = function () {
    return user;
};
```

```
var userName = require('./f2.js');
// ...
console.log(userName.user());
```